# No transform from [summit_xl_...] to [summit_xl_base_footprint]

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

When running the launch file for the summit_xl_description files [URDF's] it loads into rviz but with these errors under RobotModel. I understand I can edit the fixed frame value by typing into the Global Options > Fixed Frame textbox but the tag is loads with [summit_xl_base_footprint] is the only one that returns an OK transform for that RobotModel attribute. Changing the textbox string to one that matches a RobotModel attribute will allow an OK transform for that attribute, but only one at a time.

NOTE: For some reason all four wheels appear at the base of the robot and idk why.

How do I ensure that they all perform OK transformations?

[image]

Comment: You should look at the output of `rqt_tf_tree`. It will give you a full mapping of all the transforms. The error is probably because you having missing joints in your URDF